# Dynamic routing on Gatsby not working when linking to same path with different Id

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create client-only routes for a blog section of my app. I'm using @reach/router and all routes are working perfectly, except when I'm linking to a page that has the same path but different id, in which case it navigates to the proper url but the content does not change. I figured it has something to do with having the same path, but I can't figure out how to work around this.

This is my router:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <ArticleRouter>
        <Article path="/articles/:articleId" />
      </ArticleRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Router;

This is the code on gatsby-node.js

  if (page.path.match(/^\/articles/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/articles/*"
    // Update the page.
    // createPage(page)
    createPage({
      path:"/articles",
      matchPath:"/articles/*",
      component:path.resolve("src/pages/articles.js")
    })
  } 

And this is the code on the module.

export const Article = ({ articleId = 1 }) => {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ArticleComponent articleId={articleId} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

This is the component with the link, which renders inside the page created dinamically, and links to other articles

const ArticleLinkCard = ({
  title,
  id
}) => {

  return (
    <Link
    to={`/articles/${id}`}
    replace={true}
    >
      <article
        key={id}
      >
        <h3>{title}</h3>
      </article>
    </Link>
  );
};


As I said, I have links all over the app and they all work perfectly. The issue arises when I have a link to another article inside a single article page. I think it gets confused, but I don't know how or how to fix it. I've read the client-only-routes and every tutorial I could find, but haven't been able to find anything related to the issue. Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/reach/router/issues/225

I think the solution from @TreTuna should work for you.